# Error reading parquet file (nodeJS)-parquetjs module

Tags: javascript, node.js

My experience with nodejs is pretty basic, so please bear with me. I'm experimenting with writing and reading parquet files with:

https://github.com/ironSource/parquetjs

I am following the example there (using node 8) and have successfully written 'fruits.parquet'

However, when I attempt to read it:

```
async function read() {
let reader = await parquetjs.ParquetReader.openFile('fruits.parquet');

let cursor = reader.getCursor();
let record = null;
while (record = await cursor.next()) {
    console.log(record);
}
}
read();
```

I get:

Debugger attached.
(node:14795) [DEP0062] DeprecationWarning: `node --inspect --debug-brk` is deprecated. Please use `node --inspect-brk` instead.
(node:14795) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: read failed
(node:14795) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect..

Any ideas how to debug this-it happens on the openFile('fruits.parquet')
I know that the file exists and I also have tried to ensure read/write access to all on the file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`parquetjs.ParquetReader.openFile('fruits.parquet');`

result in a rejected promise (likely the file location is not correct).

The problem is that the error is not handled and somehow "swallowed"

try to catch the error to properly debug it:

```
try {
   let reader = await parquetjs.ParquetReader.openFile('fruits.parquet');
} catch (e){
  console.log(e); // or breakpoint, etc
  throw e;
}
```

Comment: Error: read failed
    at fs.read (/home/streamsadmin/code/streaming-pipelines-api/node_modules/parquetjs/lib/util.js:112:23)
    at FSReqWrap.wrapper [as oncomplete] (fs.js:650:17)
(node:24056) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: read failed
(node:24056) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Thank you, but I'm still getting the above error

Comment: parquet error is not very explicit. I think you should dig in parquet method parquetjs/lib/util.js:112:23 etc. Basically following the stacktrace (forget about the Deprecation warning)

Comment: Did anyone figured out problem with reading parquet using some Javascript library?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not exactly on debugging your problem but alternative solution.
To open a local file, I used following code with [parquetjs-lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parquetjs-lite) package, hope this is somewhat useful. Also parquetjs-lite helps read s3 bucket file

```
   const parquet = require("parquetjs-lite");    

   const readParquetFile = async () => {

  // create new ParquetReader
  let reader = await parquet.ParquetReader.openFile("fruits.parquet");

  // create a new cursor
  let cursor = reader.getCursor();

  // read all records from the file and print them
  let record = null;

  while ((record = await cursor.next())) {
    console.log(record);
  }

  await reader.close();
}
```

And don't forget to close the reader at the end.

I'm new to answering stackoverflow, so ignore if it's not useful.

Comment: This does not really answer the question asked, so it may be good advise but should be given as an extra to a full answer which solves the OPs problem